# Trigonometry identity help: $\frac{2\cos\ 2x}{\cos\ x}$ and $2 \cos^2\ x-1$

Tags: trigonometry

My math book has a trigonometry identity $\frac{2\cos2x}{\cos x}$ and they simplify it to $2\cos^2x-1$ but do not show the steps.  I have tried many time to simplify but can never get the same answer.

Comment: Doesn't look true: [see this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282cos%282x%29%29%2Fcos%28x%29+-%282cos^2%28x%29-1%29)

Comment: $2\cos^2x-1$ is identically equal to $\cos(2x)$, which is definitely NOT identically equal to $2\cos(2x)/\cos x$. Someone has a typo. (Or worse than a typo ... I'm not even seeing what the book *might have* intended.)

Comment: $\frac{2\cos2x}{\cos x}$ is an expression; it is not an identity.  Where's the equal sign?

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $\cos2 x = \left(2\cos^2 (x) - 1\right)$ to get:

$$\frac{2\cos(2x)}{\cos(x)} = \frac{2\left(2 \cos^2(x)-1\right)}{\cos(x)} = 4\cos(x)-\frac{2}{\cos(x)}$$

**EDIT** : The solution implies that $$\frac{2\cos(2x)}{\cos(x)}\neq 2 \cos^2(x)-1.$$

Comment: Doesn't seem to be an answer to the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apperantly $2\cos 2x/\cos x\neq 2\cos^2 x-1$.

Comment: Indeed. So perhaps you ought to call attention to that in your answer, since that seems to be the point.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the comment.